# How to disable item from different component in Angular

Tags: html, angular

So I have Tags component and I imported that component in my Chart-details component. In my Chart Details component I have a checkbox that will disable all the input box, drop down box, buttons that are located inside chart-details page but some reason my imported tags component is not disabling when I click the checkbox. Any suggestion or help on how to fix this so that a user cannot add or remove tags when the checkbox is clicked will be really appreciated.

Chart Details Component. HTML

```
//Check box to disable all the input, drop down, buttons
    <mat-checkbox *ngIf="chart && workspace" color="primary" [disabled]="this.workspace.type === WorkspaceType.user"
        [(ngModel)]="chart.isPublished" (ngModelChange)="publishChange($event)">Published</mat-checkbox>

//Example Button
   <button color="primary" mat-flat-button (click)="saveClick()" [disabled]="this.chart.isPublished">Save</button>

// Imported Tags Component
        <mc-tags [_normalTags]="chart.tags" [removable]="true" [selectable]="true"
        (added)="tagAdded($event)" (removed)="tagRemoved($event)" [disabled]="this.chart.isPublished" >
        </mc-tags>
```

I have added [disabled]="this.chart.isPublished" but I got an error saying "Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'mc-tags'. ". Also I tried (disabled) but still not working and user can still add or remove tags even though checkbox is checked.

Tags Component.HTML

```
        <mat-chip-list #chipList [disabled]="true">
            <mat-chip *ngFor="let chip of normalTags" [selectable]="selectable" 
            [removable]="removable"
                (removed)="removeTags(chip)">
                {{chip.tag}}
            </mat-chip>

            <input matInput #input [(ngModel)]="tagIn" [formControl]="tagCtrl2" 
            [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
        </mat-chip-list>
```

Right now I have to do [disabled]="true" on mat-chip-list in Tags component.html so that user can't add or remove it. I don't want to hard code this and want to control this using Chart Detail Component Checkbox.

[The disable matchip and input look like this (PIC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly7Xp.png)

It's not gonna run but I've attached the whole code for these two component over here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wwfcai . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you declared "@Input() disabled" in your child component class?

In Child.component.ts

```
@Input() disabled: any;
    ngOnInit() {
         if(disabled){
              //set properties to true/false accordingly
         }
}
```

In Parent.component.html

```
[disabled]="this.workspace.type === WorkspaceType.user"
```